# Html5 video paused at specific time VideoFrame

Tags: javascript, html, video

For a project i need to pause a video at a very specific time.
In order to be precise i watch the frame of the video using VideoFrame.

[demo here](http://fiddle.jshell.net/2lasoul/znahbzac/)

It's works but i don't understand why i need to click twice to relanch the video.
Any ideas or others solutions ? Thanks

Comment: What browser did you use? Fiddle works fine in newest Firefox (i have to click only once)

Comment: I use Firefox 36.0 and have to click twice _sometimes_.

Comment: Ok, i manage to reproduce the problem by refeshing the page. You call video.video.play(); after click but it seems like browser thinking that it is the same frame for a while, so it pause again. Just try to push one frame forward before calling play().

Comment: The video **doesn’t pause** sometimes. Especially when writing the HTML output is also being skipped (happens because of browser lag).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Push the video 1 frame after checking frame:

```
 if(frame == 23) {
    video.stopListen();
    video.video.pause();
    video.seekForward(1);
 }
```

and play the video after setting up event listener:

```
video.listen('frame');
video.video.play();
```