# Javascript pause loop till event

Tags: javascript, loops, for-loop, video, event-listener

I have javascript question,this is part of my code:

```
for(var a = 0; a < videos.length; a++) {
    source.setAttribute('src', videos[a]);
    video.load();
    video.play();

    for(var b = 0; b < times[a].length; b++) {
            video.addEventListener("timeupdate", function() {
            if (this.currentTime >= times[a][b]) {
                    this.pause();
                    var answer = prompt("Please answer the question", "Answer");
                }
            }, false);
    }
}
```

In the array `videos` I have links to video and in the array `times` I have times when to pause video for every video differently.

My aim is to start one video then pause video at certain times and resume after the question is answered,then when the video ends start another video and ask questions again. My for loops does everything instantly and it doesn't work as I want. I came up with 2 solutions:

1. Pause loops till event is reached.
2. Do it with event listeners.

I have no idea how to do it any way, so I am asking for your help.

Comment: Do you handle the case where the user pause the video? The actual time interval used for playing the video will then be different with the expected value.

Comment: This related question might help: [Html5 video paused at specific time VideoFrame](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28952762/html5-video-paused-at-specific-time-videoframe) Run the example code in the answer to see it work.

Comment: Not seeing all the code but why loop and create an event handler multiple time for the video element. It would probably be a lot easier to just bind it once and simply check if the current time is in the list and act then.

Comment: Also this code would probably have an issue around the value of `b` as it is not isolated with the scope of the handler and therefore be the same value for all.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should drop the `for` loops and work only with events. Something like this should clear out at least a few problems:

```
    var a = 0;
    video.src = videos[a];
    video.load();
    video.play();
    check_time();

    //instead of looping through your video, you wait until one is finished 
    //to play the next one.
    video.addEventListener("ended", function(){
        a++;
        if(a<videos.length){
            video.src = videos[a];
            check_time();

    } 
   //this will add event listener each time video is changed.     
   function check_time(){
        var b = 0;
        video.removeEventListener("timeupdate")
        video.addEventListener("timeupdate", function() {
             if (this.currentTime >= times[a][b]) {
                 this.pause();
                 var answer = prompt("Please answer the question", "Answer");
                 b++;
                }
            }, false);
      }
```